# Pull Data Into Individual Web Part

Tags: 2013, development, web-part, javascript, xslt

I know what I would like to do, but I do not know how to search to find the best solution.  I have a list of URLs on a list that link to stories.  I do not want the user to see the entire list of URLs.

So I was thinking of creating a new page and add a web part for each URL I want the user to see.  But I do not know the best way.  Would I use a content editor web part? OR a content query web part?  I believe scripting will be required to pull the data, right?

UPDATE:  The page that list the URL/titles is NOT a SharePoint page, but a third party web page.  I only want the URLs that are relevant.

Comment: What determines if you want a user to see a URL or not? Could you just add a 'Show In List' boolean column to your list, and then create a view filtered by Show In List = Yes?

Comment: What is your logic for showing a URL (List item) to a particular user? Have you tried enabling target audience in the list settings?

Comment: if you enable target audience then you can use a content query web part to pull items and apply audience filtering.

Comment: @TedN. Thank you for response.  That is create suggestion.  I just updated my question.  The page that list the URLs/Titles is not a SharePoint page.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @HarryB Thank you for your response and very good points.  I updated the question.  The page that lists the URLs/titles is not a SharePoint page.  It's a third party page (i.e. news hot topics).  I don't want to show the whole list. So, I thought I could call particular URLs to a web part.  I guess this could be similar to a RSS Feed Web Part but not my intentions are.  You said a content query web part would be the best way, right?

Comment: if the page provides a RSS feed then as you said RSS feed web part can be used. I have used that web part to pull a number of news feeds into our intranet. You can filter the content using XSLT or even jquery after the content is pulled on to your SP page. CQWP only applies to SharePoint content. If there is no RSS feed/other api then it wont be that straightforward. Have a look here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/597907/open-webpage-and-parse-it-using-javascript